# flask sqlalchemy quickstart

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I new in flask and sqlalchemy.

First i successfully installed flask, copied and run it in http://127.0.0.1:5000/ like described here:

[flask-quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)

next i tried:

[flask-sqlalchemy-quickstart](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/)

## error can't read

but get error can't read:

```
m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects$ from flask-hello-worl/ import db
from: can't read /var/mail/flask-hello-worl/
m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects$ from flask-hello-worl import db
from: can't read /var/mail/flask-hello-worl
m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects$
```

i thought it would create an empty sqLite automatically? I don't understand what the bug is telling me.
What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need first to activate your virtual environment

```
m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects$ cd flask-hello-worl
m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects/flask-hello-worl$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects/flask-hello-worl$
```

then run `flask shell` command

```
(venv) m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects/flask-hello-worl$ flask shell
[...]
>>> from yourapplication import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

#### Note

it's recommended to create `.flaskenv` file at the root of your project, where you specify variable enthronement:

```
FLASK_APP=app:create_app()  # or app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=0

# FLASK_RUN_EXTRA_FILES=
# FLASK_RUN_HOST=
# FLASK_RUN_PORT=8080
# FLASK_RUN_CERT=
# FLASK_RUN_KEY=
```

then you can simply run your app using this command `flask run`.

refer to:

- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#dotenv and don't forget to install `python-dotenv` package as dependency
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application

Comment: `m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/PycharmProjects/flask-hello-worl$ source ./activate` -> `bash: ./activate: No such file or directory`

Comment: anyway just try to activate your virtual environment since you did it with the first tutorial as you said

Comment: ~/PycharmProjects/flask-hello-worl$ ./msFlaskApplication.py ./activate
bash: ./msFlaskApplication.py: Permission denied

Comment: sudo ./msFlaskApplication.py ./activate
sudo: ./msFlaskApplication.py: command not found

Comment: itred as before activate : https://i.imgur.com/gDOohKr.png Error: Did not provide "LASK_APP" evironment variable, and a "ssgi.py or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory. Of course not. hmmm. confursed

Comment: @SL5net perfect, i'll update my answer based on that screenshot and it should work.

Comment: was needet: `pip install python-dotenv`, `flask shell` ==> `Error: Could not locate a Flask application.` https://i.imgur.com/VW0PCM2.png

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sl5net/99f7aae4053664db1eb0c3d2a175c105

Comment: i guess, in `.flaskenv` file, try `FLASK_APP=flask-hello-worl_hello.py` the python file where you instantiated `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: changed `FLASK_APP=app:create_app()` ==> `FLASK_APP=flask-hello-worl_hello.py` ==> Error not change: `flask shell` ==> `Error: Could not locate a Flask application.`

Comment: try `echo $FLASK_APP` if empty maybe you should open new terminal so the environment vars (in `.flaskenv`) can be taken. (don't forget then to activate venv)

Comment: echo $FLASK_APP is empty. new terminal not helps. BTW is missing in the online instructions: `pip install -U Flask-SQLAlchemy` but the error message still remains afterwards